# I can't find my hard drive after erasing partitons

Tags: hard-drive, hardware

After I installed Ubuntu on my ssd, I go to chech my other drive and I decide to format it because it had some old windows files. After I erased the partitions my hard drive just dissapeared from the screen.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where was the hard drive on the screen? Try to explain what you did specifically, what you expected to happen, and what really happened.

Comment: Did you create a new partition after erasing the old ones?

Comment: @AleksandrKaprizkin Yes I did create another partition usig FAT.

Comment: @AlexP It was under "My Computer"